# Akka Actor - Asking message gives me a Empty Set

Tags: scala, akka

In order to avoid using a mutable variable inside an `Actor`, I made the following things :

```
    import akka._
    import akka.actor._
    import play.api.Logger
    import scala.language.implicitConversions

    object Sessions_Buffer {

      case class Sessions_Buffer_Data(
        data: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, List[Array[Byte]]]
      )

      // var sessions_buffer: Map[String, List[Array[Byte]]] = Map()
      def props(): Props = Props(Sessions_Buffer())
    }

    case class Sessions_Buffer() extends Actor {

      import Sessions_Buffer._
    def receive = active(Map())

      def mergeMaps(m1: Map[String, List[Array[Byte]]], m2: Map[String, List[Array[Byte]]]) =
        for ((key, values) <- m2) yield {
          val existingData = m1.getOrElse(key, List())
          (key -> (existingData ++ values))
        }

      def active(dataFromKafka: Map[String, List[Array[Byte]]]): Receive = {
        case sessionData: Sessions_Buffer_Data =>
          context.become(active(mergeMaps(dataFromKafka, sessionData.data)))
          for ((key, values) <- dataFromKafka) {
            Logger.debug("key = " + key + " values =" + values.size)
          }
        case "get_session_data" =>
          sender() ! dataFromKafka
      }

class Test_Kakfa_To_Buffer
    extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test-kafka-buffer"))
    with ImplicitSender
    with WordSpecLike
    with Matchers
    with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  var kafkaProps: Properties = _

  override def beforeAll = {
    Play.start(TestUtils.FAKE_APP)
    kafkaProps = KafkaConfigService.securedDeviceKafkaProps
  }

  override def afterAll = {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
    Play.stop(TestUtils.FAKE_APP)
  }

val buffer_Dispatcher = system.actorOf(Sessions_Buffer.props())
... // some process here 
val futureSessionsData = buffer_Dispatcher ? "get_session_data"
val sessionsData: Map[String, List[Array[Byte]]] =
```

Await.result(futureSessionsData,timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Map[String, List[Array[Byte]]]]
    assert(sessionsData.keys.size == (TestUtils.NUMBER_OF_DEVICES + 1))
        }

The problem is that in one unit test that I wrote, when I'm asking the session_data, the resulting Map is empty.The output error from scalatest :

```
Set() had size 0 instead of expected size 4
```

During the process, the logs shows that the Map is not empty but when I'm asking this map, it's empty ! What I'm missing ?

Comment: Could you please show your remaining test code? (where you actually send the messages). I've noticed that your `merge` function may have a bug - you are not considering keys that are on `m1` but not on `m2`.

Comment: Which messages ? Because in the code that I post, I ask to the buffer_actor the data. And you're right about the merge function.

Comment: The problem is that what you are printing in your Log is different from what you are returning in the message `"get_session_data"`. Because your method `merge` is buggy, you are having an `Set` with size 0 as a result - but you print the message data, and not the result of the `merge` invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your code is structured correctly, but there are two problems that is causing this "weird" behaviour:

1. Your `merge` function has a bug - it does not consider keys which are in `m1` but not on `m2`.
2. You are logging the content of the `sessionData` message, but what you are returning as a result of `get_session_data` is the `merge` of the `sessionData` content with the previous content.

I believe if you fix these two issues you will have what you are looking for!

Comment: Yes, fixing my `mergeMaps` solved my problem ! thanks :)